# Camel Debugger is not found in classpath. Please add camel-debug or camel-debug-starter JAR to your project dependencies

Tags: apache-camel, spring-camel, camel-spring-dsl

I am using Apache Camel with Springboot

```
 <dependency>   
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.3</version>
<dependency> 

 // Apache Camel
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>3.11.5</version>
</dependency>
```

For debugging camel routes, I am adding

```
       <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-debug</artifactId>
            <version>3.15.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

After adding the camel-debug dependency, random errors are occurring in

> org.apache.camel.spi.DebuggerFactory

Most common one is :

```
Build step org.apache.camel.quarkus.core.deployment.CamelProcessor#factoryFinderResolver threw an exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/camel/spi/DebuggerFactory
...
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.camel.spi.DebuggerFactory
...
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/camel/spi/DebuggerFactory
...
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.camel.spi.DebuggerFactory
```

Comment: please try to use the same version of camel an camel spring boot

Comment: @LucaBurgazzoli tried to use the same version but maven not able - didn't find the dependency with version 3.11.5

Comment: Yeah, you need to have everything on 3.15.0